Is there a way to keep track of the sequence of moves in my chess engine
I have my chess engine, and while it is searching, I want it to keep track of the best move of the current position and the sequence of the follow-up moves.
Getting the best move for the current position is easy- it's the goal of the search. But I want the sequence for debugging.
Here's my code for the engine:
public static Move StartSearch(int depth)
    {
        bestMove = Move.NullMove;

        // Return Null Move
        if (depth <= 0)
        {
            return bestMove;
        }
        
        Search(depth, Infinity.negativeInfinity, Infinity.positiveInfinity, 0);

        return bestMove;
    }

public static int Search(int depth, int alpha, int beta, int plyFromRoot)
    {
        // Try looking up the current position in the transposition table.
        // If the same position has already been searched to at least an equal depth
        // to the search we're doing now,we can just use the recorded evaluation.
        int ttVal = tt.LookupEvaluation (depth, plyFromRoot, alpha, beta);
        if (ttVal != TranspositionTable.lookupFailed)
        {
            // The Transposition Table cannot store the repetition data, so whenever a position is repeated, the engine ends up in a threefold draw. To prevent that, check if it's threefold once again!
            // For simplicity, just check if previous position is already reached
            if (board.positionHistory.ContainsKey(board.currentZobristKey))
            {
                return 0;
            }

            Move move = tt.GetStoredMove ();

            if (plyFromRoot == 0)
            {
                bestMove = move;
            }

            return ttVal;
        }

        if (depth == 0)
        {
            return QuiescenceSearch(alpha, beta);
        }

        List<Move> legalMoves = MoveGen.GenerateMoves(board);

        MateChecker.MateState mateState = MateChecker.GetPositionState(board, legalMoves);
        if (mateState != MateChecker.MateState.None)
        {
            if (mateState == MateChecker.MateState.Checkmate)
            {
                return -Evaluation.checkmateEval + plyFromRoot;
            }

            return 0;
        }

        MoveOrder.GetOrderedList(legalMoves);

        if (plyFromRoot == 0)
        {
            bestMove = legalMoves[0];
        }

        int evalType = TranspositionTable.UpperBound;

        foreach (Move move in legalMoves)
        {
            board.MakeMove(move);

            int eval = -Search(depth - 1, -beta, -alpha, plyFromRoot + 1);

            board.UnmakeMove(move);

            if (eval >= beta)
            {
                tt.StoreEvaluation (depth, plyFromRoot, beta, TranspositionTable.LowerBound, move);
                return beta;
            }

            if (eval > alpha)
            {
                alpha = eval;
                evalType = TranspositionTable.Exact;
                
                if (plyFromRoot == 0)
                {
                    bestMove = move;
                }
            }

            tt.StoreEvaluation (depth, plyFromRoot, alpha, evalType, bestMove);
        }

        return alpha;
    }

I tried making an array for the sequence but could not figure out how to get the best move for each depth.
Please let me know where I should change or add to my code!
(Also, if you find something weird in my alpha-beta pruning or transposition table, please let me know!)

I've rolled back your edit. Please DO NOT edit the tag information back into the title. The tag information works extremely well here and doesn't need any help, and adding the tags to the title is just unnecessary noise.

https://www.chessprogramming.org/Principal_Variation

Look into tt.StoreEvaluation(). Is bestMove being stored there?

There are a few ways to do this. The first way is to use a triangular PV table, which can be found at https://www.chessprogramming.org/Triangular_PV-Table. Another way you could do it is to store the best move of a position into your transposition table (you will have to do this anyway since TT moves dramatically improve move ordering) and retrieve the PV as if iterating over a linked list. The first approach is generally used since the second method can suffer truncated PV lines in case one of the entries are replaced due to hash collision.
